# Virtual functions empty definition in Base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I understand that return values with co-variant types can differ in case of virtual functions. I wish to know *if there is a possible way* through which I can have an empty declaration in my base class's virtual function without *returning NULL* and still not having this:

**Error: no return statement in function returning non-void**

I do not wish to use pure virtual functions as it will clutter all derived classes with empty declarations of the virtual function.

Is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: If you declare your function to return something, and you don't actually return anything, what do you want your function to do?

Comment: Doing what you ask would introduce undefined behavior. You really don't want undefined behavior do you?

Comment: You can have "empty" base class for your return type, and return its instance in your base class virtual function...

Comment: Is it intended that the base class functions should never be called? In that case, you could make them throw an exception, if you really don't want to make them pure virtual. (Otherwise, they really will need to return something).

Comment: Why not make the base function pure-virtual?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Is there a way to throw an exception in base class func() definition by default if function resolves at base class. So that i can define the func() in the required derived class and others just throw exception. Also is "assert(false) followed by return NULL" in base class func() definition equally good?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj: Not by default, no. You'd have to write the `throw` yourself. I don't know what you mean by "equally good" - `assert` would behave differently, so choose the behaviour you want.

Comment: @VineetDeoraj: if I understand your question to Mike correctly, then  perhaps what you want is a non-pure virtual function `virtual void func() { throw std::runtime_error("not supported"); }`...?  The `assert`/`return` idea is a bit dangerous, if you enable assertins in your testing, how can you test that the client code handles NULLs when running in production?

Comment: @TonyD Still the throw needs to be followed by return NULL right? And doesn't the program terminate after assert, thus never actually executing return NULL ?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj a throw leaves the function without executing any following statement (unless it's from without a try/catch block internal to the function), so no - it doesn't need to be followed by a return NULL.  Many implementations of assert terminate or do nothing depending on another macro definition, which means they can be disabled for a "production" build that prioritorises performance over checking, hoping any bugs that could have led to a failed assertion will have been fixed in dev/testing.  Check NDEBUG at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: @TonyD Sorry if i am being too repetitive, but for the sake of function's return value i do have to return a NULL right even if i am using exceptions?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj If you throw unconditionally, then you don't need to return a NULL.  If you throw conditionally, you only need a "return <something>" from other code paths.  See http://ideone.com/ma3Q4z for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if their is a possible way through which i can have an empty declaration in my base class's virtual function without returning NULL and still not having [error]

Certainly not.  If you have a function that's declared to return a value, why would you expect to be able to define it not to?  If the function's pure virtual, then you don't *"clutter all derived classes with empty declarations of the virtual function"*, you leave it pure virtual until you have a meaningful value to return (or use NULL).  It makes no sense to talk of having an non-abstract class where the function doesn't work as implied by the declaration: if that's the way your classes are shaping up, you should consider removing the function from the API, reconsidering why you're opposed to NULL, or throwing an exception instead.

Comment: The Base class is anyways abstract, i meant is there no way to to not declare/define pure virtual functions in the derived classes which are  not significant to this function.

Comment: In any specific derived class you do not have to declare/define the pure virtual functions, but if you do not do so then that class remains abstract and you'll still need to define the function in a further-derived class before you can instantiate anything.  By "significant to this function" I assume you're saying the derived class doesn't actually have any use for the function - if that's true then either 1) it should not be derived form a base class that includes the function, or 2) the API should allow some "not supported" behaviour such as NULL, an exception, `bool can_do_xyz() const` etc.

Comment: You may want to read about "fat interfaces", which seem to be what you're trying to write, and their pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

So your base class function must return some value, and the type must be co-variant with the return type(s) you will use in your derived class (which naturally brings to mind base-class-pointers and derived-class-pointers).

Your requirement is that you want to avoid passing a NULL pointer.  One possibility would be to create a particular [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) (some kind of object representing a lack of any meaningful result, as opposed to an actual NULL pointer)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could return a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for the base type return type.

Comment: Even though the web page you linked to is not likely to disappear it's still not a good idea to provide what qualifies as a "link only answer". Including the link is _ok_ but you need to add a little more substance. Try to add more meat to your soup otherwise it's going to get flagged or downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ STandard

> 2 A return statement with neither an expression nor a braced-init-list
>   can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a
>   function with the return type cv void,

And

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no
>   value; this results in undefined  behavior in a value-returning
>   function.

I do not see the reason why the virtual function in your base class can not be declared as a pure virtual function if you have no its realization.